# how overloaded datatype is getting called from functor

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, functor

Call to functor :

```
   double average=std::for_each(values.begin(),values.end(),CalculateAverage());
```

Above code will call functor CalculateAverage,

but from inside of "void operator () (double elem)",
where "operator double() const" is getting called.

functor is defined like this:

```
class CalculateAverage
{
private:
   std::size_t num;
   double sum;
public:

   CalculateAverage() : num (0) , sum (0)
   {
   }

   void operator () (double elem) 
   {
      num++; 
      sum += elem;
   }

   operator double() const
   {
       return sum / num;
   }
};
```

Comment: Calm down. And try to communicate your problem (question) clearly

Comment: Have you tried reading the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)?

Comment: sorry, i mean to say where this declaration "operator double() const" is getting called and who is calling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How and where double() const is getting called ?

[`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) returns the function object.

Normally it is done like:

```
CalculateAverage average=std::for_each(values.begin(),values.end(),CalculateAverage());
```

But in your case `average` gets converted to `double` because of the overload present in your class.

You have provided a conversion operator due to which it is called.

Answer (score 0):

> How and where double() const is getting called ?

the overload of `std::for_each` you are using returns functor which you have passed as a third parameter. When it is returned compiler is applying user defined conversion. In your case it is implicit, so no need for cast.

You can make it explicit, then you will have to cast result to double:

```
explicit operator double() const
```

and:

```
double average=static_cast<double>(std::for_each(values.begin(),values.end(),CalculateAverage()));
```